# Can I localize a UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, uidatepicker

I'm trying to localize a UIDatePicker. Apple's docs say that it should autodetect the current locale, yet the language stays the same, no matter what language I select. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 11):

The locale property (and all other country specific format properties for that matter) defaults to the value returned by [currentLocale](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/currentLocale), which in turns depends on the iphone's country settings, not the language settings. You need to set the appropriate country in the iphone general settings.

Comment: locale for NSDatepicker is deprecated in ios 5.1

Comment: Check kraag22 and Dave DeLong's comments at FunkyKat answer below

Answer (score 5):

NSLocale in UIDatePicker is back since iOS 6. Phone settings in iOS 6 are ignored and used en_US locale by default, so you must set locale in code

Comment: if you set locale property in iOS 5.1.1 it works well too. Phone/Pad settings are ignored too

Comment: If you create a `UIDatePicker` programmatically, it'll be initialized with `[NSLocale currentLocale]`.  If you're creating it in a xib, then make sure the value of the "Locale" attribute is "Default", and *not* "English (United States)".

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, in **iOS5** UIDatePicker seems to ignore the set locale and use the locale provided from the general settings. But it should work fine in **iOS6**.

Comment: Yes, I did. It was an application developed entirely for Arabic. I set the locale from the storyboard and **viewDidLoad** and the date picker 's locale was English, under iOS5, as the simulator's settings were.
However, it worked for iOS6 just from the storyboard without setting it from **viewDidLoad**.

Sorry for the late reply, I just saw your comment.

Answer (score 0):

the UIDatePicker has a [locale](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/locale) property; if you don't set it it should default to the user's preferred locale.  When you say "no matter what language I select" what do you mean--are you trying to change the locale programmatically, or are you changing the device's default locale using the Settings page?

Comment: I'm referring to the International setting in Preferences. I have everything else set up to be an NSLocalizedString, and it all translates wonderfully. However, say I set the language to French in Preferences. My UIDatePicker will not display months in French. I have not set the locale at all, so I figured that this should display the correct locale. However, it's not.

Comment: how are you initializing the date picker?  are you leaving the locale and calendar properties set to nil, or are you setting them to something?

Comment: Also, I'm initializing the datePicker completely by code. Here's my code on pastebin. 

http://pastebin.com/m51df66f7

Answer (score 0):

To show the picker with the current language setted in the device, use this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView;

[_pickerView setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]]];
```