# How to remve AM/PM from UIdatePIcker

Tags: objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

i need UIdatePIcker to choose month/hour/minute and don't want AM or PM. We don't use this in my region. Really i can't find simple solution for this. Just to create my own UIdatePicker.

Maybe someone had done this and could share how to remove Am/PM ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The date picker will display time based on current locale, so for US you get am/pm, for Ukraine I would get 24 hour selector. Apple recommends that you stick with users locale, but you can override it using `locale` property. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140388/how-to-disable-am-pm-in-uidatepicker) for more discussion.

Comment: I just tried to change in xib local to Ukraine but it don't override AM/PM they still appears. I found many posts that this isn't really easy to do

Comment: The date/time format in date pickers etc. depends on your "region format" settings, not the language, those are separate settings.

Comment: How i could change region format ? and find all supported region list