# UIDatePicker locale does nothing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, locale

I'm creating a UIDatePicker programmatically, and setting its locale with the following code:

```
datePicker.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"] autorelease];
```

The datepicker still appears in English (or whatever language I've set the phone to).  Anyone have any idea why this does nothing, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered here [Can I localize a UIDatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151335/can-i-localize-a-uidatepicker/2265984#2265984), the picker display depends on country settings, not on language settings.

In your example you are changing the language locale only.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the locale of the UIDatePicker's calendar as well:

```
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"] autorelease];
datePicker.locale = locale; 
datePicker.calendar = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];
```