# UIDatePicker NSLocale doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uidatepicker

In my app i have changed my language to arabic from iPhone settings and when i open the app the app shows date picker in Arabic language.
I used the NSLocale to show date picker in English language even if the language is set to Arabic in iPhone's Settings.
Here is my code.

```
datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
NSLocale * locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
datePicker.locale = locale;
```

But when i select the date it returns me in Arabic language but in picker it shows date in US language format.
Please help.
[gone through different links but didn't find my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151335/can-i-localize-a-uidatepicker/2265984#2265984)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151335/can-i-localize-a-uidatepicker/2265984#2265984

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIDatePicker locale does nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648719/uidatepicker-locale-does-nothing)

Comment: Looking at both of the "duplicates" listed above, neither appears to provide a real answer.  I'm guessing that you need to set the `calendar` property, but I haven't tried that.