# UIDatePicker Localizatiion Problem

Tags: iphone

How to Localized UIDatePicker according to language selection from the application.
UIDatePicker has locale property so how to use please give idea.

Thank You.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151335/can-i-localize-a-uidatepicker/2265984#2265984 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894161/uidatepicker-problem-localizing/2918507#2918507, the picker display depends on country settings, not on language settings.

Answer (score 1):

I know nscalendar has different calendaridendifiers for different locales maybe there is a way to set the pickers calendar source?

So yeah I just checked the docs and there are properties you can set for a calendar a locale etc. Just use that by default it uses nil which is defaults to the users current locale as it's calendar source.