# How to set the UIDatePicker in 24hours in ios5?

Tags: ios, ios5, uidatepicker

Please help me. I have a bug in iOS5 thats set the locale into 12-hours mode in iOS6 is working fine.

this are my code.

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];

[self.timePickerView setLocale:locale];
[self.timePickerView setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[self.timePickerView setDate:self.date animated:NO];
```

what is wrong with my code? I want to have a default 24hours on my UIDatePicker. please help me thanks!

Comment: Check out the answers in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151335/can-i-localize-a-uidatepicker/2265984#2265984

Comment: For UIDatePicker you cannot change the time format to 24 or 12, it depends on the user local settings in setting.app please visit this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151187/show-time-in-12-and-24-hour-format-in-uidatepicker-on-the-basis-of-app-settings and please try to find Solution using Google First